# When is it ok to change a tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, badges, tag-wiki

I see that that there is a badge:

> **Research Assistant**
> *Edited 50 tag wikis.*

Not many people have it, just under 200 people. Which tells me that this is something that the Community does not really need as tags should not change often. But when should the tags change?

Comment: Thanks for making the question look much better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you feel that you can positively improve a tag wiki, you could edit it. Remember to be unbiased and factual, citing sources or creating links to off-site documents when possible to help supplement your content.

A relevant piece from the [Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> ### What should I write in the tag wiki?
>
> See the guidelines in the [blog post announcing tag wikis in their
> current form](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/). To summarize:
>
> - The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.
> - Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.
> - Concentrate on what a tag means to your community.
> - Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.

If you have less than 20,000 reputation, all your edits [will need to be approved by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) via the [Suggested Edits review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits).